# OctoberCMS Related Model Dynamic Default Value

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms

I have a backend controller implements `Backend\Behaviors\RelationController`, I just want to set default values for the related model depending on the parent model values.

I have tried the following: `model.beforeCreate`, `formExtendFields` but no luck.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

After whole day of searching, I found the solution, it is documented no where on [OctoberCMS website](https://octobercms.com/docs), I inspected the source file `Backend\Behaviors\RelationController`, after that I came with the below solution.

You should implement `relationExtendViewWidget` on your controller, then you can access the model from: `$widget->model`, something like below:

```
class Members extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [
        'Backend\Behaviors\RelationController',
    ];

    public function relationExtendViewWidget($widget, $field)
    {
        $member = Member::findOrFail($this->params[0]);

        $widget->model->course_id = $member->course_id;
        $widget->model->member_id = $member->id;
    }

    public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field)
    {
        $member = Member::findOrFail($this->params[0]);

        $widget->model->course_id = $member->course_id;
        $widget->model->member_id = $member->id;
    }
}
```

I believe this should be documented somewhere on [OctoberCMS documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/)

Comment: Don't hesitate to create an issue here: https://github.com/octobercms/docs/issues to request adding the missing document.

Comment: There's no need for this line: `$member = Member::findOrFail($this->params[0]);`

The parent model is passed in as the third argument to both methods you exemplified.

Comment: Please create an issue https://github.com/octobercms/docs/issues and I'll be sure to remember to document those methods. Otherwise I can pretty much guarantee that I'll forget.

Comment: I removed the first line as you mentioned, now I'm getting `Missing argument 3 for Walid\Gedc\Controllers\Members::relationExtendViewWidget(), called in /Users/walid/Projects/my-project/modules/backend/Behaviors/RelationController.php on line 345`

Comment: That is expected because the function signature in RelationController is `public function relationExtendManageWidget($widget, $field)`

Comment: What build are you on?